# U+FFFD � special characters are being inserted inside a string in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

So I'm trying to prepend a `<br>` tag in front of the longest word encountered in a given string in PHP. The strings I'm working with may also contain characters from various languages, but all the strings are encoded in UTF-8.

```
// Here I'm prepending a <br> tag before the longest word in $words which is a subset of $string
substr_replace($string, "<br>", strpos($string , $words[$longest]) - 1, 0);
```

But I've noticed that when I modify a string of Korean or Russian text with this line of code, a U+FFFD  character gets inserted, even replacing some characters in the string. Would anyone have a clue as to why that occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this built in function nl2br [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php ]

its un-defined character in the set [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block) ] so its kinda like null.

I would base64_encode  [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php ] before storing and base64_decode [http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php] before serving the data.

Alternatively you can try utf8_encode [ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php ] and utf8_decode [ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php ]

Also UTF-8 Character set ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 )

Comment: How does base64encode/decode help the user get a line break into their content?

Comment: suggesting how to preserve the string. Mentioned when modifying multi-lingual string null values are entered.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I was trying to incorporate PHP's multibyte functions into my code but to no avail. I will see if nl2br works.